# Trouble porting math code between javascript and java

Tags: java, javascript, maps

I have trouble porting javascript code that converts between Latitude/Longitude & OS National Grid Reference points, to Java. (http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html)

I am getting different results in some of the mathematical operations.
I have included the *javascript* and *java* code below, but what happens is the `Ma` calculation results in  `0.04195508514183418` in *javascript* and `0.04195511450680837` in *java*. I have printed off the inputs to the calculation and they are the same.

This is the *javascript* code:

```
OsGridRef.osGridToLatLong = function(gridref) {
     var E = gridref.easting;
     var N = gridref.northing;

     var a = 6377563.396, b = 6356256.910;              // Airy 1830 major & minor semi-axes
     var F0 = 0.9996012717;                             // NatGrid scale factor on central meridian
     var lat0 = 49*Math.PI/180, lon0 = -2*Math.PI/180;  // NatGrid true origin
     var N0 = -100000, E0 = 400000;                     // northing & easting of true origin, metres
     var e2 = 1 - (b*b)/(a*a);                          // eccentricity squared
     var n = (a-b)/(a+b), n2 = n*n, n3 = n*n*n;

     var lat=lat0, M=0;
     var count = 0;

     do {

       count++;
       lat = (N-N0-M)/(a*F0) + lat;

       console.log("pre ma calc");
                console.log("n = " + n);
                console.log("n2 = " + n2);
                console.log("n3 = " + n3);
                console.log("lat = " + lat);
                console.log("lat0 = " + lat0);

       var Ma = (1 + n + (5/4)*n2 + (5/4)*n3) * (lat-lat0);

        console.log("post ma calc ma = " + Ma);
```

This is the output:

```
pre ma calc test.html:68
n = 0.0016732202503250534 test.html:69
n2 = 0.0000027996660060978346 test.html:70
n3 = 4.684457855549562e-9 test.html:71
lat = 0.8970962185213205 test.html:72
lat0 = 0.8552113334772214 test.html:73
post ma calc ma = 0.04195511450680837
```

And here is the java code:

```
LatLon osGridToLatLong(OsGridRef osGridRef) {

        int E = osGridRef.easting;
          int N = osGridRef.northing;


          double a = 6377563.396, b = 6356256.910;              // Airy 1830 major & minor semi-axes
          double F0 = 0.9996012717;                             // NatGrid scale factor on central meridian
          double lat0 = 49*Math.PI/180, lon0 = -2*Math.PI/180;  // NatGrid true origin
          double N0 = -100000, E0 = 400000;                     // northing & easting of true origin, metres
          double e2 = 1 - (b*b)/(a*a);                          // eccentricity squared
          double n = (a-b)/(a+b), n2 = n*n, n3 = n*n*n;

          double lat=lat0, M=0;


          int count = 0;
          do {
              count++;
            lat = (N-N0-M)/(a*F0) + lat;

            Log.e(TAG, "pre ma calc");
            Log.e(TAG, "n = " + n);
            Log.e(TAG, "n2 = " + n2);
            Log.e(TAG, "n3 = " + n3);
            Log.e(TAG, "lat = " + lat);
            Log.e(TAG, "lat0 = " + lat0);

            double Ma = (1 + n + (5/4)*n2 + (5/4)*n3) * (lat-lat0);
            Log.e(TAG, "post ma calc ma = " + String.valueOf(Ma));

            double Mb = (3*n + 3*n*n + (21/8)*n3) * Math.sin(lat-lat0) * Math.cos(lat+lat0);
            double Mc = ((15/8)*n2 + (15/8)*n3) * Math.sin(2*(lat-lat0)) * Math.cos(2*(lat+lat0));
            double Md = (35/24)*n3 * Math.sin(3*(lat-lat0)) * Math.cos(3*(lat+lat0));
            M = b * F0 * (Ma - Mb + Mc - Md);                // meridional arc


          } while (N-N0-M >= 0.00001);  // ie until < 0.01mm
```

This is the output:

```
07-03 12:36:03.413: E/DSDS(779): pre ma calc
07-03 12:36:03.423: E/DSDS(779): n = 0.0016732202503250534
07-03 12:36:03.423: E/DSDS(779): n2 = 2.7996660060978346E-6
07-03 12:36:03.443: E/DSDS(779): n3 = 4.684457855549562E-9
07-03 12:36:03.473: E/DSDS(779): lat = 0.8970962185213205
07-03 12:36:03.473: E/DSDS(779): lat0 = 0.8552113334772214
07-03 12:36:03.473: E/DSDS(779): post ma calc ma = 0.04195508514183418
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`5/4` will be interpreted as an integer divison and therefore will yield `5 / 4 = 1.25 =  1`

Change it to `5.0 / 4` so it will use floating point types instead of integers. That is the case in the calculation of Ma, Mb, Mc and Md multiple times.

Maybe that already makes your results even, but it surely makes them right as far as the math should work itself. I think you migrated the code correctly besides that.

Comment: Indeed, it says so right on the web page the OP referenced: *"Typed languages may need explicit casts to give floating-point results"*.