# Convert OSGridRef in GeoJSON for MongoDB index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geojson

I have a massive geojson file with a bunch of objects like this:

```json
{
    "_id": "75961B3B-758D-4011-BFDD-CC2172A01AFA",
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "fictitious": "false",
        "class": "Unclassified",
        "roadNumber": null,
        "name1": "Thornborough Avenue",
        "name1_lang": null,
        "name2": null,
        "name2_lang": null,
        "formOfWay": "Single Carriageway",
        "length": 30,
        "primary": "false",
        "trunkRoad": "false",
        "loop": "false",
        "startNode": "0FDE4A7F-F95E-434D-9DB8-447886575130",
        "endNode": "950A78DC-46A5-4393-BB29-DACFF2FB7B85",
        "structure": null,
        "nameTOID": "osgb4000000030537584",
        "numberTOID": null,
        "function": "Local Road"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [581458, 197055, 0],
                [581473, 197057, 0],
                [581488, 197059, 0]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to  create an index for these in mongodb, but the coordinates in these documents are in OSGridRef format instead of latitude and longitude, which mongodb cannot work with, and therefore throws an error.

Any idea if theres a quick way to convert these? Or an option in mongodb that im unaware of?

Here is an image of the error i get:
[image]

Comment: See [GeoJson Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#geojson-objects) in the MongoDB documentation.  Those latitude and longitude values are not valid.

Comment: @Joe as i said in the post, they are not latitude or longitude values. my question is about how to convert these.

Comment: The question is tangential, but there is sample code for doing that conversion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449413/trouble-porting-math-code-between-javascript-and-java, or you might try one of the on-line converters.